# Checking if an update already took place in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using the following code, to combine several tables into 1 single Table called `DB_Total`:

```
INSERT INTO DB_Total
SELECT *
FROM Tags_DI_DB;
```

But, if I (accidentally) execute this query twice or three times, the data just gets stacked. Is there a possibility to check wether or not a table is added in  the new "mastertable", `DB_Total`?

Comment: If you had at least one (if not a combination) of primary keys on your table then it would prevent the records from being inserted multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DB_TOTAL
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Tags_DI_DB a
        LEFT JOIN DB_TOTAL b
            ON a.colName = b.colName
WHERE   b.colName IS NULL
```

where `colName` is the unique column

Comment: I don't think I get this. You are checking to see if a.colName = NULL?

Comment: @Gutanoth when `b.colName IS NULL` that means the record doesn't exist yet o table `DB_TOTAL`

Comment: So if I have a Column named " NAME" my code should look like this:

INSERT INTO DB_TOTAL
SELECT *
FROM    Tags_DI_DB a
        LEFT JOIN DB_TOTAL b
            ON a.NAME = b.NAME
WHERE   b.NAME IS NULL

Comment: exactly. did you try the query?

Comment: Yes, when I execute the query, it gives me an error(roughly translated from Dutch):

`Dual output destination NAME`